# Are these pests or ladybird larvae?

Tags: identification, bugs

These bugs started to appear on one of my rose plants. I don't want to kill them if they are not pests. They seem like they could be ladybird larvae but i want to be sure. They are quite small, less than a 1cm in length.

Can anyone confirm what they are?

[image: bugs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they seem to be from a ladybird. Which one I cannot see (there are many species), see [here](https://www.atroposbooks.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/a/ladybird-larvae.jpg) for example for a few that are common in the UK.

The ladybird larvae feed on aphids, so I think that's why you find them on your roses.

Comment: Thanks, i think it might be the 7 spot one from those pictures.